# Handle multiple result from a stored procedure with SqlQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns a multiple set of results (two tables). I call the stored procedure like this:

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<RefererStatisticResult>(
"exec [dbo].[GetReferrer] @StartDate, @EndDate, @Source",
this.CreateInParam("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, startDate),
this.CreateInParam("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, endDate),
this.CreateInParam("@Source", SqlDbType.SmallInt, eventSourveVal)).ToArray();
```

My RefererStatisticResult contains two List<> properties, for the result set, but the lists are empty after the call. How can I handle the result set? Is it possible with the SqlQuery?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `DbContext` has no native support for materialising multiple resultsets. However, it is reasonably straight forward to achieve by dropping down to the `ObjectContext` and using the `Translate` method to copy results from a `DbDataReader` into entities in your domain model.

Here's some example code. This assumes your `ReferrerStatisticResult` is just a container for the two lists called `Set1` and `Set2`. Obviously adjust according to your actual domain model.

```
// Create container ready for the resultsets
var result = new RefererStatisticResult();

using (var myContext = new MyContext())
{
    // Create command from the context in order to execute
    // the `GetReferrer` proc
    var command = myContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetReferrer]";
    // add in command parameters
    // (not shown)

    try
    {
        myContext.Connection.Open();
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Drop down to the wrapped `ObjectContext` to get access to
        // the `Translate` method
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)myContext).ObjectContext;

        // Read Entity1 from the first resultset
        result.Set1 = objectContext.Translate<Entity1>(reader, "Set1", MergeOptions.AppendOnly);

        // Read Entity2 from the second resultset
        reader.NextResult();
        result.Set2 = objectContext.Translate<Entity2>(reader, "Set2", MergeOptions.AppendOnly);        
    }
    finally
    {
        myContext.Database.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: To translate a non EF model/entity, do not specify the entity set name: `var data = objectContext.Translate<CustomEntity>(reader).ToList();`

Comment: It's `MergeOption` not with ending `s`

Answer (score 0):

I think following code could help you.

```
 MultiResultDomain domainEntity = new MultiResultDomain();
     var command = _DatabaseContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
     command.CommandText = "[dbo].[SPR_GETMultipleResultSP]";
     command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     try
     {
         _DatabaseContext.Database.Connection.Open();
         var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

     List<customcustomer> _listOfCustomer =
     ((IObjectContextAdapter)_DatabaseContext).ObjectContext.Translate<customcustomer>
     (reader).ToList();
         reader.NextResult();
         List<customproduct> _listOfProduct =
             ((IObjectContextAdapter)_DatabaseContext).ObjectContext.Translate<customproduct>
     (reader).ToList();

         foreach (var cust in _listOfCustomer)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Name: Mr.{0} And Country: {1}", cust.FirstName,
             cust.Country);
         }

         foreach (var product in _listOfProduct)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("ProductName: {0} And Package: {1}",
             product.ProductName, product.Package);
         }

         domainEntity.Customer = _listOfCustomer;
         domainEntity.Product = _listOfProduct;
         return domainEntity;
```

Ref: [Click here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1072284/Return-Multiple-Result-Set-using-Entity-Framework)

Comment: The accepted answer does exactly this. No reason to repeat it.