# Using Dbcontext with a stored proc, how can I include values for IEnumerables in the Dbo?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, dbcontext

Let's say I have a **Dependents** table, like this

```
Id | Name | EmployeeId
1  | Luke | 1
2  | Leia | 1
3  | Tim  | 4
```

And then I have an **Employees** table, like this

```
Id | EmployeeName | JobTitle
1  | Anakin       | Enforcer
2  | Tarkin       | Senior Vice President
3  | Palpatine    | CEO
```

For dependents, EmployeeId is a foreign key connecting them to the Employees table. Finally, I have an EmployeeDbo class, like this:

```
public class EmployeeDbo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DependentDbo> Dependents { get; set; }
}
```

So as you can see, the EmployeeDbo includes the dependents as a collection. Using LINQ and DbContext, getting all employees with a populated list would just be `var results = _dbContext.Employees.Include(x => x.Dependents).ToList()`

Here's my problem. I'm using a stored procedure to select the data I want. The actual data is much more complicated, but here's what my code calling the stored proc looks like:

```
var employees = 
    _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<EmployeeDbo>(@"[GetEmployees] @someParameter", sqlParam);
```

This returns an object of type `DbRawSqlQuery<EmployeeDbo>`. When I call `ToList()` the actual SQL call is performed, but it does NOT populate my dbo's `IEnumerable<Dependent>` collection, it just comes back as null. I can't do `Include()` on the DbRawSqlQuery.

What are my options for populating my Dbo's Dependent collection with this call to the stored proc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle multiple result from a stored procedure with SqlQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304791/handle-multiple-result-from-a-stored-procedure-with-sqlquery)

Comment: By the way, could be wrong but don't think that is the correct way to execute a stored procedure (I think it works just inefficient as it's not doing a direct RPC call on that proc, it's executing a separate batch that calls it)

Comment: @Charlieface The stored procedure in question does not return multiple result sets, but maybe I can modify it to return the data I'm asking for. I'll take a look at that, thanks.

Comment: Attach output your stored proc